# Uso correcto de flash[:success]

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buenas tardes, necesito de vuestra ayuda.

Necesito mostrar un mensaje de éxito o rechazo, una vez insertado un objeto en BD. 
Hasta el momento solo lo he logrado actualizando la ventana del navegador, no automáticamente (como debiera ser), una vez gatillado el evento *submit*.

cotizacions_controller.rb

```
def create
  @cotizacion = Cotizacion.new(cotizacion_params)

  if @cotizacion.save
    flash[:success] = "Su tasación esta siendo procesada"
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @cotizacion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

_header.html.erb

```
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="header-content-inner">
      <h1>Negocia tu Auto</h1>
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
          <%= value %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= render :partial =>'cotizacions/form' , locals: { cotizacion: @cotizacion } %>
    </div>
  </div>  
</header>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: cotizacion, scope: :cotizacion) do |form| %>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="field">
          <%= form.text_field :patente, 
                              placeholder: "Patente", 
                              id: :car_patente, 
                              class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-inline">
          <%= form.select :marca, 
                          options_for_select([["SUBARU", "t"], ["KIA", "s"]], id: :car_marca), 
                          prompt: "Marca", 
                          class: "combobox form-control",
                          name: "inline"%>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="field">
          <%= form.text_field :modelo, 
                              id: :car_modelo, 
                              placeholder: "Modelo Ej: Yaris, i10",
                              class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ... -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset">
        <div class="actions">
          <%= form.submit  class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg', value: 'Tasar su Vehículo' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Lo esperado como imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea una vez mostrado el mensaje, es volver a mostrar la página de inicio, después de 1 segundo, sin el mensaje y el formulario limpio.

Estructura de proyecto es la siguiente.

[image: Estructura Proyecto]

creatives/index.html.erb

```
       <%= render 'navbar' %>
       <%= render 'header' %>
       <%= render 'services' %>
       <%= render 'portfolio' %>
       <%= render 'call_to_action' %>
       <%= render 'contact' %>
```

Archivo cotizacions/new.html.erb

```
               <h1>New Cotizacion</h1>

              <%= render 'form', cotizacion: @cotizacion %>

              <%= link_to 'Back', cotizacions_path %>
```

Archivo routes.rb

```
           Rails.application.routes.draw do
              get 'creatives/index'
              root :to => 'creatives#index'
              resources :cotizacions
              post 'creatives/index', to: 'cotizacions#create' 
            end
```

Nuevo comportamiento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo log

Started POST "/creatives/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-01 10:00:45 -0400
Processing by CotizacionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6Y0r+8y7M5DJUeF7Gt2CziIEpMef4nLN8s6bvRA9jr+CHN2gRMGFaEzVgX/UnVc2YsCtNCH1DEs6cfi71r3PrA==", "cotizacion"=>{"patente"=>"congetenriutes", "marca"=>"", "modelo"=>"", "kilometraje"=>"", "correo"=>"", "telefono"=>"", "abs"=>"0", "aire_acondicionado"=>"0", "airbag"=>"0", "velocidad_crucero"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Tasar su Vehículo"}
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "cotizacions" ("patente", "marca", "modelo", "kilometraje", "correo", "telefono", "abs", "aire_acondicionado", "airbag", "velocidad_crucero", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["patente", "congetenriutes"], ["marca", ""], ["modelo", ""], ["kilometraje", ""], ["correo", ""], ["telefono", ""], ["abs", "f"], ["aire_acondicionado", "f"], ["airbag", "f"], ["velocidad_crucero", "f"], ["created_at", "2017-08-01 14:00:45.399154"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-01 14:00:45.399154"]]
  [1m[35m (1.7ms)[0m  [1m[36mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/creatives/index
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-01 10:00:47 -0400
Processing by CreativesController#index as HTML
  Rendering creatives/index.html.erb within layouts/creative
  Rendered creatives/_navbar.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered cotizacions/_form.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered creatives/_header.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendered creatives/_services.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered creatives/_portfolio.html.erb (4.8ms)
  Rendered creatives/_call_to_action.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered creatives/_contact.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered creatives/index.html.erb within layouts/creative (18.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 48.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hasta el momento solo lo he logrado actualizando la ventana del
>   navegador, ...

Al utilizar `form_with`, estás enviando la forma con `ajax`, sin embargo la acción `create` del controlador no está respondiendo al formato indicado después de guardar exitosamente una cotización (i.e. `if @cotizacion.save`).

Esto genera un error en tu página (el cual debes poder ver en el log del servidor) y no se genera ninguna acción que pueda llamar al mensaje `flash` (i.e. no hay `render` ni `respond_to`, solo un error), por lo que no se muestra el mensaje `flash` (incluso después de utilizar `flash.now`).

Si tu interés es seguir utilizando `ajax` entonces debes cambiar como muestras los mensajes flash, pues con `ajax` solo actualizas una parte de la página (i.e. deberías hacerlo manualmente).

Sin embargo no creo que estés buscando utilizar `ajax`, así que te recomiendo utilizar el atributo `local` en tu forma para evitarlo:

```
<%= form_with(model: cotizacion, scope: :cotizacion, local: true) do |form| %>
```

Y la acción `create` del controlador utiliza `redirect_to`<sup>1</sup>:

```
def create
  @cotizacion = Cotizacion.new(cotizacion_params)

  if @cotizacion.save
    flash[:success] = "Su tasación esta siendo procesada"
    redirect_to cotizacions_path
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @cotizacion.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Donde `cotizacions_path` debe coincidir con la ruta de la acción `index`.

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Se mantiene el uso de `flash` debido a que se incorporó un `redirect_to` en lugar de `render`.*</sup>

> La idea una vez mostrado el mensaje, es volver a mostrar la página de
>   inicio, después de 1 segundo, sin el mensaje y el formulario limpio.

Para esto puedes utilizar *JavaScript*/*JQuery*, que te permitirán **esconder** el mensaje de error después de un tiempo determinado; por ejemplo, podrías hacer lo siguiente para que esto suceda con cualquier mensaje (o mensajes) que recibas por medio de `flash`:

**_header.html.erb**

```
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
    <div class="header-content-inner">
      <h1>Negocia tu Auto</h1>
      <div id="error">
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <%= value %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <%= render :partial =>'cotizacions/form' , locals: { cotizacion: @cotizacion } %>
    </div>
  </div>  
</header>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#error').animate({ height: 0, opacity: 0 }, 'slow');
    }, 1000);
   });
</script>
```

Se agregó un `div` adicional para encapsular el mensaje (o mensajes) de `flash`, al cual haces referencia en el *script* (i.e. `$('#error')`) para ocultarlo después del tiempo definido (i.e. `1000`).

---

#### `flash` vs `flash.now`

Con `flash` se mantiene el valor asignado hasta la siguiente petición, por lo tanto se recomienda su uso previo a un `redirect_to`; por ejemplo:

```
flash[:success] = "Su tasación esta siendo procesada"
redirect_to cotizacions_path
```

En cambio, `flash.now` solo muestra el valor en la petición actual (después de un `render`), eliminándolo de la siguiente petición, por lo tanto funciona únicamente tras utilizar `render`, por ejemplo:

```
flash.now[:success] = "Su tasación esta siendo procesada"
render :index
```

Es importante destacar que con `flash` también se tiene el valor disponible en la petición actual (e.g. después de hacer `render`) pero el mensaje no desaparecerá en la siguiente petición.

Comment: realice lo indicado, pero no tuve éxito, de echo al actualizar la pagina ahora, el msje ("Su tasación esta siendo procesada" no se muestra.

Comment: @SebastianCamposDavila ¿Podrías mostrar el código de `create.html.erb`?

Comment: Hola @Gerry, no tengo un archivo create.html.erb, te adjunto la estructura del proyecto, además del código que pienso solicitas. Gracias!

Comment: @SebastianCamposDavila Ya vi el problema, en tu caso particular no es debido al uso de `flash`, se debe al uso de `form_with`. Revisa la pregunta actualizada para más detalle.

Comment: @SebastianCamposDavila También he agregado una solución para ocultar el mensaje después de 1 segundo; mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: aplicare lo indicado y les cometo, Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Lamentablemente sigo con el mismo comportamiento, solo al actualizar obtengo el resultado esperado. Ahora se duplica el msje. El script para que desaparezca funciona perfecto. He notado que al quitar el código get 'creatives/index', del archivo routes, dejo de recibir los msjes.

Comment: @SebastianCamposDavila ¿podrías mostrar el log del servidor que se genera la hacer el `submit`?

Comment: agregado, no veo errores mmmm....

Comment: Es muy extraño que te muestre doble mensaje, pareciera que dentro de algún otro parcial repites el llamado de `flash`. ¿Te es viable compartir algún repositorio con el código para que pueda mirarlo?

Comment: Perdón @Gerry, si funciona correctamente!!!!, tengo que ver por que se esta duplicando el msje solamente. Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: Para cerrar efectivamente estaba llamando 2 veces al msje desde otro parcial, que era el mismo _header.html.erb. Funciona perfecto, tanto el script como la funcionalidad, ahora viene la siguiente etapa, manejo de errores.... Muchas graciass!!!!

Comment: @SebastianCamposDavila Excelente! Suerte!